# Visual Studio 2010 - The "Services" tab

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, service

I'm trying to enable client application services in my project:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384312.aspx

My project is based off of .Net Framework 4.0 (not the client profile).

My application isn't an Asp.Net application. I go to Properties and I can't find the services tab.  What am I missing?

Comment: I think I started it as an empty project or a winForms project. I don't remember.  Is there I way I can convert it without too much hassle?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new Windows Forms project, then copy the old code to the new project, build it and get it to work.

*Then* you should use the "Services" tab.

Comment: No, there isn't. Why? Is it a problem to copy some files?